# Remove extra white spaces from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The elements in my list should be
A1,A2,A3,A4

If user input A1,A2,A3,A4,,,,,,
or
A1,A2,,,A3,A4,,A5,,
or
A,B, ,, ,,  V,,,,       ,    ,    ,    ,                ,ddfd ,,,,,,,,

It should consider as

A1,A2,A3,A4

The logic written by me was

```
if(valueText !== null) {    alert("Value Text..." + valueText);    
                    valueList = valueText.split(",");

                    for (var i = 0; i < valueList.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (valueList[i] == "")
                        {
                            valueList.splice(i, 1);
                            alert("ValueList inside for if.."+valueList);
                        }
                    }
                    alert("ValueList.." + valueList);
            }
```

But its not working properly

Comment: Try if (!valueList[i]) instead of if (valueList[i] == "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regex, for example:

```
var txt = 'A1,A2,,,A3,A4,,A5,,'

var res = txt.replace(/(,)\1*/g, ',').replace(/,$/, '');
//^ A1,A2,A3,A4,A5
```

Comment: Instead of using replace I want it logical.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with `match` & `join` functions:-

```
var str = "A1,A2,,,A3,A4,,A5,,";
strnew = str.match(/[^ ,]+/g).join(',');
//Output--> A1,A2,A3,A4,A5
```

Hope this will help you...